# How to wrap implementation using C++20 modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, boost-geometry, c++-modules

I'm having trouble wrapping the boost geometry implementation of comparable distance. I'm unsure if it is because I'm using modules incorrectly or there is something in boost geometry itself.
In the module file I have:

```
module;

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

export module module_interface;
export import "point.hpp"; // Defines MyPoint as a plain struct with members float x, y; 
export {
    BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(MyPoint, float, cs::cartesian, x, y)
};

namespace m3 {
    export template <typename A>
        auto MyFunc(A& a, A& b) {
        return boost::geometry::comparable_distance(a, b);
    }

    export auto MyFunc2() {
        MyPoint a{ 0,0 }, b{ 1, 1 };
        return MyFunc(a, b);
    }
};
```

And in the calling program I have:

```
#include <iostream>
import module_interface;

using namespace m3;

int main() {

    MyPoint a{ 0,0 }, b{ 1, 1 };
        
    auto t = m3::MyFunc(a, b); // I want to do this, but it does not compile
    auto t1 = m3::MyFunc2(); // this does compiles and may help isolate problem
}
```

When I compile I get a lengthy error (which I find unhelpful, but maybe it helps you)

```
> include\boost\geometry\strategies\cartesian\distance_pythagoras.hpp(235,1):
> error C3967: error importing 'type' from module 'module_interface'
> include\boost\geometry\strategies\comparable_distance_result.hpp(48):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::strategy::distance::services::return_type<boost::geometry::strategy::distance::comparable::pythagoras<CalculationType>,MyPoint,MyPoint>'
> being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>           
> CalculationType=void 1>        ]
> include\boost\geometry\strategies\comparable_distance_result.hpp(61):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::resolve_strategy::comparable_distance_result<Geometry1,Geometry2,boost::geometry::strategy::distance::services::default_strategy<boost::geometry::point_tag,boost::geometry::point_tag,MyPoint,MyPoint,boost::geometry::cartesian_tag,boost::geometry::cartesian_tag,void>::type,true>'
> being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>           
> Geometry1=MyPoint, 1>            Geometry2=MyPoint 1>        ]
> include\boost\geometry\strategies\comparable_distance_result.hpp(132):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::resolve_strategy::comparable_distance_result<Geometry1,Geometry2,Strategy,true>'
> being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>           
> Geometry1=MyPoint, 1>            Geometry2=MyPoint, 1>           
> Strategy=boost::geometry::default_strategy 1>        ]
include\boost\geometry\strategies\comparable_distance_result.hpp(243):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::resolve_variant::comparable_distance_result<Geometry1,Geometry2,Strategy>'
> being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>           
> Geometry1=MyPoint, 1>            Geometry2=MyPoint, 1>           
> Strategy=boost::geometry::default_strategy 1>        ]
include\boost\geometry\strategies\comparable_distance_result.hpp(248):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::comparable_distance_result<Geometry1,Geometry2,boost::geometry::default_strategy>'
> being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>           
> Geometry1=MyPoint, 1>            Geometry2=MyPoint 1>        ]
> include\boost\geometry\strategies\default_comparable_distance_result.hpp(37):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::comparable_distance_result<Geometry1,Geometry2,void>'
> being compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>           
> Geometry1=MyPoint, 1>            Geometry2=MyPoint 1>        ]
> 1>test_modules\module_interface\module_interface.ixx(15):
> message : see reference to class template instantiation
> 'boost::geometry::default_comparable_distance_result<A,A>' being
> compiled 1>        with 1>        [ 1>            A=MyPoint 1>       
> ]
> 1>include\boost\geometry\algorithms\detail\comparable_distance\interface.hpp(358):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation
> 'default_comparable_distance_result<Geometry1,Geometry2>::type
> boost::geometry::comparable_distance(const Geometry1 &,const Geometry2
> &)' being compiled
> 1>test_modules\module_consumer\consumer.cpp(10):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation 'auto
> m3::MyFunc<MyPoint>(A &,A &)' being compiled 1>        with 1>       
> [ 1>            A=MyPoint 1>        ]
```

Comment: What compiler and version are you using? What are the compilation flags? At least my Clang 12.0.1 does not accept `export import "point.hpp";` in the first place.

Comment: I am using latest visual studio 2019 and vs 2020 preview. I think export import is legal c++20, but here it isn't that important. It just allows the main program to avoid using #include "point.hpp". In that case, the module can simply import "point.hpp";

Comment: I am not sure. The code compiles fine on Clang if instead of `export import "point.hpp";` I simply insert `export struct MyPoint { float x; float y; };`. Can you try to insert that into your code and see if that works with VS. I do not have a Windows PC nearby and in particular not one with VS2020 (With Windows 11 this won't change to the better either). And the modules support of online compilers is limited - not-existing.

Comment: Similarly it also compiles if I just put `#include "point.hpp"` below `export module`/`import module` in the `.cpp` and `.cppm` files. As said I have never seen `export import` so far.

Comment: Thanks for working through this on another compiler. I tried both suggestions on VS and while I can compile the module, I can't compile the main program. Maybe VS compiler is not quite ready for modules yet....

Comment: You are welcome! I am sorry I can't help more. Said versions compile on Ubuntu 18.04 with Clang 12.0.1 and Boost 1.65.1.0. From what I have seen none of the major compiler fully support modules yet. Historically VisualStudio has always been slow with ISO-C++ support so I'd be not surprised if it is a short-coming of VisualStudio.